# Unable to get value from appsettings.json

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

In newly created asp.net core 2.0 web API project I want to use values from appsettings.json:

```
{
  "JWTSettings": 
  {
    "SecretKey": "blahblahbla",
    "Issuer": "QuinCApi",
    "Audience": "http://localhost:10080/",
    "LifeTimeInMinutes": 1
  }
}
```

And created model for this

```
public class JWTSettings
{
    public string SecretKey { get; set; }
    public string Issuer { get; set; }
    public string Audience { get; set; }
    public int LifeTimeInMinutes { get; set; }
}
```

In Startup.cs I've registered it with the following method:

In constructor:

```
IConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

In ConfigureServices method:

```
var appSettings = Configuration.GetSection("JWTSettings");
         services.Configure<JWTSettings>(appSettings);
```

Then using DI I'm trying to get value, but it **sometimes** returns normal value for some of the fields and sometimes (practically always) returns "ValuesAPI", but not the real value. What am I doing wrong?

P.S. Configuration.GetValue<>() does the same trick.

Comment: Can you post the code where you are using DI to access the values from the model class? Also what do you mean by "it sometimes returns normal value for some of the fields and sometimes (practically always) returns "ValuesAPI",

Comment: Can you add what values are you getting using DI?

Answer (score 0):

In the method where you are using DI to access the properties of the model class
`JWTSettings` you should follow the below approach using  `IOptions<T>` pattern in .NET Core.

```
public SampleDIMethod(IOptions<JWTSettings> settings)
{
 //returns an object of type JWTSettings
  var securitySettings = settings.Value; 
 }
```

Please refer to the link below

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration